# Journal sent review request to my supervisor but the email was addressed to me

Tags: peer-review, journals

My PhD supervisor received an email from a journal asking for review of an article. However, the email was addressed as "Dear {my name}". Even the journal office created an account in my name on Editorial Manager to access the manuscript (as mentioned in the email).

My supervisor is not interested in accepting the review request since the email was not addressed to him. Now I am not sure how to proceed from here.

UPDATE: Per @wimi 's answer, I contacted the editor asking if I was the intended email recipient and expressing my willingness to review. The editor clarified that there was indeed an email mess-up and I have been invited to review the manuscript!

Comment: There's a good chance this happened because the journal got your email through an already-published paper. That paper would have the list of authors, their affiliations, and contacts, and the journal messed up which email belongs to which author.

Comment: Is it possible it's some sort of (phishing) scam? Is this a reputable journal? Do you or your supervisor  have a prior association to them ? Could it be a clerical error?

Comment: @lan W The journal is indeed reputed (indexed in Scopus and Science Citation Index). We do not have a prior association though. It seems a clerical error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your supervisor does not want to accept this review request. Your course of action depends on whether **you** want to review the manuscript:

- if you **do** want to review the manuscript, contact the editor letting them know about the mistake, asking whether you were the intended recipient, and expressing your willingness to accept the review. If the editor confirms that you were the intended reviewer, or that your review would be welcome, proceed with the review.
- if you do **not** want to review the manuscript, just reject the request. It might be worth contacting the editor anyway and letting them know about the mistake, in order to make sure that future review requests arrive at the intended recipient.